# How to create an iterative calculations till optimal solution for any given formula in excel?

Tags: excel

I have prepared a sheet [EMI interest rate calculator](https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArPjpEz9zTtEokOx030qWV8t8HZS?e=YU3b0j)

I am using Newton Raphson method to find interest rate for EMI loan. It works and finds a requisite interest rate. But the problem is that, it covers almost 5000 cells for iterations (especially for column U, V and W which calculates value as per Newton Raphson Method) and make file/processing very heavy. So I want to calculate as iterations and reduce file/processing size.

Kindly help me.

Comment: *As a loop calculations and reduce total cell numbers from 5000 to 2-5.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What is the formula you want to change and why did you not succeed?

Comment: Formula given in the column V and W, which indicates formula as per Newton Raphson method, it expands by 1st, 2nd, 3rd and so on considering the result of previous values till the optimum results becomes.

Comment: Why not just use Excel's native *`IRR`* function which also uses iteration? By the way, with regard to your Column `I`, to compute annual rate from Monthly rate the formula would be `(1+monthly_ rate)^12-1`. Your calculation is the same as merely `monthly_rate*12`

Comment: Where in your question is that? Please update.

Comment: The column U, V and W which marked as red.

Comment: https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/financial/loan-calculator.php.      Finding the interest rate is a complex calculation involving the Newton-Raphson Method which you can read about at MathWorld.

Comment: Who is that last comment directed to?

Comment: Very respectfully submitting to you sir.

Comment: I am aware of the NR method. My question, since you seem to want something faster, is why you do not use the Excel `IRR` function which uses the same method? And also why you seem to be incorrectly calculating the annual interest?

Comment: And also, `IRR` returns the same result for monthly interest as does your iterative method.

Comment: Sir, I have validated the result (IR) with calculator soup calculator and gives same result. But, as per IRR function of Excel, I am unable to understand putting variables to the Excel formula. If you suggest any example using IRR formula which solves my problem, I will be very grateful to you.

Comment: What you expect for a result is not clear. Is it the annualized rate of return for different monthly payments on a 100,000 loan or is it something else? Also, what version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Sir, web version of Excel. Variables are Principle amount =100000, Monthly EMI = 9120.5 , total month(n) = 12, interest rate on emi =? Expected result is 17. Sheet is already atached with this question

Comment: Yeah, but it's not the sheet or comments, but your question that should explain what you need. This will not help other people who may have the same problem to recognize the problem/solution.

Comment: Sir, My English skill is very poor. That is why I have attached the sheet after validation. Just only to reduce complexity/lengthiness of the sheet. Newton Raphson method is easily available in public domain. And the people who answer this question will share formula for result and snapshot for the same. It would be sufficient for upcoming viewers who have the same proble. Thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monthly Interest:
`=IRR(MAKEARRAY(13,1,LAMBDA(r,c,IF(r=1,-B1,B2))))`

Monthly Interest x 12 => your 17% but that is incorrect method

Annual Interest = (1 + Monthly Interest)^12 - 1 => 18.390%

I have added a sheet to your web instance that shows the calculations and results:

[image]

Comment: https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/financial/loan-calculator.php?given_data=find_ratepercent&pv=100000&nper=12&pmt=9120&given_data_last=find_ratepercent&action=solve.  SIR, Please view this one for once.

Comment: @RanjanKumarSingh what about it? They are merely showing the nominal interest rate. The effective interest rate is higher. You can report whichever you prefer. In the USA, effective or annualized interest rates are required in order to effectively compare different loan conditions.

Comment: I have to find the nominal interest rate as given by the online calculator i. e. 
 17 %. The sheet I have attached is also giving the same result. Column T, U, V and W are calculating functions as per NR method for finding the value of interest rate formula as given on/calculates from calculator soup website. And each time I have to calculate and compare with last one T5, U5, V5, W5,  with T6, U6, V6 and W6 which I want to reduce and trying to calculate further calculations in T5, U5, V5 and W5.